# How to the "decision/path" during recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I want to calculate the minimal costs in production by choosing lot sizes with recursion. The value I get is correct, but I also want to save the correct decisions/path(how much to produce in each period n).
 I don't know how to save it correctly. This way I just overwrite it everytime.
n = period, i = inventory, pcap = production capacity, demand[n] = how much i sell in period n,
Thanks!

```
 public double getMinC(int n, int i) {
        if(demand[n]-i > pcap) return Double.MAX_VALUE;
        if(this.n == n) {
            if(demand[n] < i) {         //not sure if i need this
                decision[n] = 0;
                return storagecost * i-demand[n];
            }
            decision[n] =  demand[n]-i;
            return varc * demand[n]-i + fixc;
        }
        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double cost = min;
        int xmin = Math.max(0, demand[n] - i);
        int xmax = Math.min(storagecap-i+demand[n], pcap);
        int bestx = -1;
        for(int x=xmin; x<=xmax; x++) {
            cost = getMinC(n+1, i+x-demand[n]) + storagecost * (i+x-demand[n]);
            if(x!=0) cost += fixc + varc * x;
            if(cost< min) {
                min = cost;
                bestx = x;
            }
        }
        decision[n] = bestx;
        return min;
    }
```

Comment: Write a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: You need an appropriate data structure (`Map`, `List`) as an instance variable in your class for holding the data. Also, you should model the data you're storing as a separate `class` (e.g. `DecisionCriteria`).

Comment: Thanks! So i can't use an array? decision[] is an instance variable. I don't know how to tell if the decision I save is part of my minimal costs... If i use a List with my code I would just save everything.

Comment: What I meant was that your `DecisionCriteria` objects could contain snapshots of the parameter values used in each iteration. It is easier to store these in a dynamic data structure instead of array because this way you don't need to worry about resizing etc. You could share some more code and context to get more & better ideas from people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should return both the value of the best decision along with the set of values that lead to that best solution. Something like:

```
struct solution {
    double min;
    int *decision;
}
```

This code:

```
         cost = getMinC(n+1, i+x-demand[n]) + storagecost * (i+x-demand[n]);
        if(x!=0) cost += fixc + varc * x;
        if(cost< min) {
            min = cost;
            bestx = x;
        }
```

should be changed to:

```
    sol = getMinC(n+1, i+x-demand[n]) + storagecost * (i+x-demand[n]);
        if(x!=0) cost += fixc + varc * x;
       if ( sol.min< minsol.min) {
            minsol.min = sol.min;
            minsol.decision=malloc (n, sizeof (int));
            minsol.decision [0]=x;
            // Copy content of sol.decision into minsol.decision starting at index 1

        }

  ...
  ...
  return minsol;
```

Note that you need to take care of deallocating the returned solution structure and take care of allocating a new solution structure to be returned.  A more efficient way would be to return a linked list instead of the array within the solution struct and append minx to the returned linked list of decisions.

This is in no way complete but I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thank you!!!<br>

So now my Code looks like this:
    `sol = getMinC(n+1, i+x-demand[n]);
   sol.min += storagecost* (i+x-demand[n]);
   if(x!=0) sol.min += fixc + varc * x;
   if(sol.min < min.min) {
    min.min = sol.min;
    while (!min.list.isEmpty()) {
           min.list.removeFirst();
       }
    min.list.add(x);
    int size = sol.list.size();
    for(int j=0; j<size; j++) {
     min.list.add(sol.list.removeFirst());
    }
   }`

Comment: Sorry, I failed at formatting and the 5 minute period to edit is over... xD